# Media codec capabilities Android

Tags: android, decoding, android-mediacodec, multimedia

We are developing an application which involves audio,video decoding and encoding. In some cases we need multiple decoders to be open at same time.

**Problem :**
Some devices doesnt support multiple(2 or more) decoders to be open at same time. This happens mostly for high resolution videos (1080p).

**Assumptions** 
We think this is happening because of hardware limitations of the devices.

We need to know is there any apis which tells us the media codec capabilities in android like maximum number of codecs that can be opened at same time in any android device. We are fine with even if the API is in native level.

Comment: @fadden can you please help .

Answer (score 0):

How about [MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.getMaxSupportedInstances()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#getMaxSupportedInstances())?

Comment: This we can use but this api is for version 23 onwards